# How to access Swift variables that are primitives in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here's an example of what I have:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var myBool : Bool!
    var myString : String!

    /*...*/
}
```

So when I create an instance of this class in Objective-C, I can access the myString, but not the myBool. It seems like Objective-C can't access primitive types whenever they are declared in Swift, unless I am missing something?

Comment: Try changing `myBool` to a non optional and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the only way I got it working was to leave off the optional/unoptional symbols (?, !).

So it worked when I changed it to simply `myBool : Bool`

Also, you may need to clean your project before it will show up in autocomplete.